# simple getopt implementation in C++

Tags: c++

I am implementing project specific "getopt" in C++.  For this I implemented a class that looks like this:

```
 class MyGetOptions {
 private:
     typedef std::map<std::string, bool> optionsTbl; 
     optionsTbl  m_optionsTbl;
     int         m_currentArg;

     // Prohibit copy and assignment.
     MyGetOptions ( const MyGetOptions &);
     void operator= (const MyGetOptions &);

 public: 
     MyGetOptions ();
     inline bool addOption(std::string option, bool isArgReq);
     int getOpt(int argc, char *argv[], std::string& option, std::string& optArg);

     // Debug functions.
     void printOptionTbl();
 };
```

Now usage of above class by providers looks as below

```
MyGetOptions myOpts;
    myOpts.addOption("myName", true);
    myOpts.addOption("mySettings", false);

    std::string optArg;
    std::string option;

    while( (myOpts.getOpt(argc, argv, option, optArg)) != -1 )
    {
        if(option.compare("myName") == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "The myName option is set and value is " << optArg << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        // ... additional options.

        else if(option.compare("?") == 0 )
        {
            // print help and exit.
        }
        else
        {
            // print help and exist.
        }
    }
```

In the present design I am returning "?" mark if `getOpt` finds an option character in `argv` that was  not registered, or if it detects a missing option argument. If all command line options have been parsed, then `getOpt` returns -1.

I want to distinguish when `?` is returned whether `argv` provided was not registered or missing option argument is provided, and also want to print the option name in while loop and show to user. What is best way to achieve this? Can any one please provide guidelines or inputs?

Comment: Why are you re-inventing the wheel?  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/program_options.html http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libgpp/libgpp_39.html http://code.google.com/p/getoptpp/ ...

Comment: Because novice wheelwrights need to practice making wheels, and should not create elaborate new designs before they can create workmanlike basic wheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using global variables, I prefer to use return values with combination with "?" like as below

```
else if ((option.compare("?") == 0) && (getOptStatus == 0))
{
    // if ? and return value 0 means finds a string in argv that is not
    // registered with add options.
    continue;
}
else if ((option.compare("?") == 0) && (getOptStatus == 1))
{
    // if ? and return value 1 means finds an option string
    // with missing option argument.
    // print help and exit.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard design for [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) has it return the option letter that it found, or `?` on error.  You would capture the option letter by assignment in the loop condition:

```
int opt;
while ((opt = myOpts.getOpt(argc, argv, option, optArg)) != -1)
{
     ...analyze the option returned...
}
```

The standard `getopt()` has a global variable `optarg` to point to the argument; the reference parameter in C++ is a better choice (we might quibble about `std::string` versus `char *`).

As to error detection, the standard `getopt()` has variables `optopt` and `opterr` to assist.  The `optopt` contains the letter of the option that triggered the error.  The `opterr` can be set to 0 to indicate that `getopt()` should not report errors; by default, it writes an error to `cerr` for you.

In C++, you would avoid using global variables, but you could use some extra (private) member variables to record such details, and provide accessor functions to let you find out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Program options have been done before.  Do not reinvent unless you really must.  Please consider [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/program_options.html).